# search and replace a string in first occurrence

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I am using the below `sed` command for search and replace operation.

```
sed -i '/searchstring/s|find string|replace string|g' filename
```

it change all the occurrences in a input file. how can i make it for only one time.

Thanks.

for example ,

```
a

a

b

b

a

c

d
```

this the input file.

command i have used like below,

```
sed -i '/a/s|a|changed|g' filename
```

output i got like below,

```
changed

changed

b

b

changed

c
```

d

ie, it made change 3 times.

but i have to change only one time.

the expected outputs is,

```
changed

a

b

b

a

c

d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i '/searchstring/s|find string|replace string|'
```

**Note:** Removed `g ( global substitution )`

As per your updation,

```
sed -i '/search/{ s/search/changed/; t loop;}; :loop; n; b loop' yourfile
```

Comment: thanks,  need is i want to replace only one time.but the given command replace string in all the lines.

Comment: +1 also for gnu sed, it could do `sed 's/foo/bar/n'` `n` is the `n-th` occurrence.

Comment: @user3304467 you should in your question specify `only first occurrence` **in the whole file**

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `g` is the correct approach, but just to show how it is done with `awk`

```
awk '/searchstring/ {sub(/find string/,"replace string")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the first occurrence in the whole file:

```
awk '!f&&/search/{sub(/find/,"replace");f=7}7' file
```

or with the `g`:

```
awk '!f&&/search/{gsub(/find/,"replace");f=7}7' file
```

is the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most elegant solution but it's very easy to understand:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ o="a";n="changed"; line=$(cat file | grep -n "$o" | cut -d: -f1| sort -n | head -1); sed -i.bak "$line s/$o/$n/g" file; cat file
changed

a

b

b

a

c

d
```

Explanation:

find the line number of the first occurrence of the match and then run the substitution on that line.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed,

```
sed '0,/searchstring/ { /searchstring/ s|find string|replace string|g }' filename
```

with any `g` flag tweaking you need.